# Node module update install

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I am using mozila MakeAPI for popcorn maker. It saves the data to elasticsearch. I added and saved a new column in elastic search. Now for retrieval, I was not able to get that column value. So I update a node module Makeapi_client.

My question is, Is this approach good? because It might be case if the user updates the npm. In this case what will happen to the code I wrote in it.

Comment: Yes, we can't write in node_modules. It will be overwritten on npm install. what could be the other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Patching" a library in this way is not recommended. Next time you update MakeAPI your changes will be overridden. You have a few options:

1. **[Submit a Pull Request](https://github.com/mozilla/MakeAPI/pulls)** - Clone the original repository, make your changes, and then create a pull request. A pull request is a request you make to the original library authors to merge your changes into their canonical library. In essence, you'll be fixing the library for everyone!
2. **Make the patch in a different file** - Nothing is stopping you from doing something like this:

   ```
   var Client = require('makeapi').Makeapi_client;
   Client.prototype.someNewMethod = function() {};
   ```

   Or something similar. In essence, creating a patch in a different file that you can check into version control, which won't get overridden by changes.

   Please note that updates to the library may still break your changes.

Comment: ok, Do you have an idea of:  makeClient.then(function (err, data, totalHits) {}) how can I add a new field to it. It is MakeAPI-client node module method.  The module has the below code: 
      // Extend wrapped with contents of make
      [ "url", "contentType", "locale", "title", "remixCount",
        "description", "author", "published", "tags", "thumbnail",
        "username", "remixedFrom", "_id", "emailHash", "createdAt",
        "updatedAt", "likes", "reports", "remixurl", "editurl" ].forEach( function( prop ) {
          wrapped[ prop ] = make[ prop ];
      });

Comment: If I adds one index value at the end of this array. It works fine for me

Comment: @DineshRawat It works fine, today. Tomorrow, when you'll update the library, it will silently disappear. Creating a pull request seems to be the way to go in your case.

Comment: Actually it doesnt seems a way. I only need to add a index. The modules allowing me only:-url
contentType
locale
title
description
author
published
tags
thumbnail
username
remixedFrom
id
emailHash
createdAt
updatedAt

Comment: Any code you modify on your own will be overridden in the next update to the library. It doesn't matter if you change 1 line or rewrite the entire library.

Comment: @DineshRawat Please read this https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/

Comment: Is there any way by which I can prevent a module not to update at all?

Comment: @DineshRawat Of course, just don't update it. But why would you want to do that? You get bug fixes and security updates through updating a module. You don't want to give that up.

Comment: hmmn, you are right? Just for the sake of knowledge, I would like to know that way. Is it possible